# How to resize ArrayList

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

I come from a C++ background and I want to have a matrix of

```
ArrayList<arrayList<E>> javamatrix
```

In C++ I would just do

```
std::vector<std::vector<T> > cppmatrix;
std::vector<T>vcol(cols);
cppmatrix.resize(rows,vcol);
```

I can't seem to find a built-in `resize()` function for `ArrayLists` for this task, so should I use another collection? Is no way to do this except using for loops with `javamatrix.add()`?

---

P.S I want it to be initialized in the constructor with its size as that size might be queried before I edit elements or add or remove.

Comment: Why do you need to resize it? ArrayLists expand automatically when needed.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I could have sworn that STL vectors also resize automatically as you push more data onto them.

Comment: @Arkain I understand what you mean but when you encounter Reservation Datastructure you need to Specify size to the array first before placing element which need to place on a specific Index.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no `resize` equivalent that automatically constructs and adds elements.  You must do this yourself.  However, [`ensureCapacity`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) is equivalent to vector's `reserve`.  It will ensure you have room, but not change the actual size.

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't need to resize arraylists.  The size you initially pass in is just its starting size.  If you attempt to add items beyond its current size, it will automatically resize.

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

Comment: You might want to resize if you want to put an object a little way beyond the end of the array, and have the gap filled in with default objects. I guess it is not really possible with the memory/object semantics Java chose though.

Comment: Another use case of resize() method would be if you want to remove all items beyond certain index. Of course you can use remove() in for cycle but resize() is more convenient and could be more optimal.

Comment: Resize needed when you have an expandable lookup table. E.g. you have until now indices up to 30 and an index of 250 comes out.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is very old already but this link may help [java arraylist ensureCapacity not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688151/java-arraylist-ensurecapacity-not-working) , The code adds "Null" value in order to adjust the current size.

Instead of using purely ensureCapacity you can have ensureSize

```
public static void ensureSize(ArrayList<?> list, int size) {

    list.ensureCapacity(size);
    while (list.size() < size) {
        list.add(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also simply use list.addAll(Collections.nCopies(size, null));

Answer (score 3):

Mostly, a 'resize()' operation is not needed because (a) ArrayList's auto-resize as you add elements, and (b) it's unclear what values you would store in the ArrayList<>, e.g. 'null' is not very useful.  E.g. in your case you'd probably need a loop anyway to create MatrixCell objects.

For those readers who want to know how to resize an ArrayList to make it *smaller*, it mystifies me why ArrayList was designed without a 'resize()' method. Perhaps it's because novice programmers are likely to see that method and then not realise that ArrayList<> auto-resizes.

In Java this idiom works to *reduce* the size of an ArrayList<>:

```
    list.subList(n,list.size()).clear();
```

It works because the 'subList' returns a List backed by the original ArrayList<>, so therefore the 'clear()' operates on the original 'ArrayList<>'.

Comment: Very bad answer that claims that "resize is not needed".  There are tons of reasons to have `resize()`.  For instance, you want an array of size `n` and you want to be able to random access the array.  Without resize it to make it size `n` at first place, you can't do `arr.get(some_index)` and `arr.set(some_index, obj)`.

Comment: @icando I presume you're thinking of sparse arrays, and I agree this is a case where a 'resize()' would be useful, although a Map might be better if it's really sparse.  If you actually want all cells in the array to be filled, then you'll need to initialise each entry to some valid reference, in which case you still need a loop.

Comment: you can also extend a Collection like this: `collection.addAll(Collections.nCopies(n, defaultElement));`  possibly not as elegant as a loop, but works

Comment: @Tim Cooper: In what way is a sparse array inferior to a map? I always assumed that a sparse array was a map, but with a concrete native index instead of an Integer index.

Comment: Not sure that the dense and inscrutable   "list.subList(n,list.size()).clear()" idiom is really superior to "while (list.size() > size) list.remove(list.size()-1)".