# java arraylist ensureCapacity not working

Tags: java, arraylist

Either I'm doing this wrong or i'm not understanding how this method works.

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.ensureCapacity(200);
a.add(190,"test");
System.out.println(a.get(190).toString());
```

I would have thought that ensureCapacity would let me insert a record with an index up to that value. Is there a different way to do this?

I get an IndexOutOfBounds error on the third line.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, `ensureCapacity` doesn't change the *logical size* of an `ArrayList` - it changes the *capacity*, which is the size the list can reach before it next needs to copy values.

You need to be very aware of the difference between a logical size (i.e. all the values in the range `[0, size)` are accessible, and adding a new element will add it at index `size`) and the capacity which is more of an implementation detail really - it's the size of the backing array used for storage.

Calling `ensureCapacity` should only ever make any difference in terms of performance (by avoiding excessive copying) - it doesn't affect the logical model of what's in the list, if you see what I mean.

EDIT: It sounds like you want a sort of `ensureSize()` method, which might look something like this:

```
public static void ensureSize(ArrayList<?> list, int size) {
    // Prevent excessive copying while we're adding
    list.ensureCapacity(size);
    while (list.size() < size) {
        list.add(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: So that's what I was thinking based off the results I saw... But is there a way to do what I need to do?

Comment: use array if you really want to have single item on position 190

Comment: Maybe using a different class rather than ArrayList?

Comment: That's right folks: I corrected a typo. This is undoubtedly the apex of my career.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: I hate to disappoint you, but that wasn't a typo. It's a range with an inclusive start and exclusive end point - the index "size" itself is *outside* the range of valid values at any time.

Comment: My parade has ended. Thanks Jon. Now I'll have to figure out how to tell my kids ;)

Answer (score 5):

So as others have mentioned `ensureCapacity` isn't for that.
It looks like you want to start out with an `ArrayList` of 200 nulls? Then this would be the simplest way to do it:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList( new String[200] ));
```

Then if you want to *replace* element 190 with "test" do:

```
a.set(190, "test");
```

This is different from

```
a.add(190, "test");
```

which will add "test" in index 190 and shift the other 9 elements up, resulting in a list of size 201.

If you know you are always going to have 200 elements it might be better to just use an array.

Comment: +1, but I was just pulling out a simple example that caused the same error for the same reason as my actual situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Ensuring capacity isn't adding items to the list. You can only get element 190 or add at element 190 if you've added 191 elements already. "Capacity" is just the number of objects the ArrayList *can* hold before it needs to resize its internal data structure (an array). If ArrayList had a getCapacity(), then doing this:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.ensureCapacity(200);
System.out.println(a.size());
System.out.println(a.getCapacity());
```

would print out 0 and some number greater than or equal to 200, respectively

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList maintains its capacity (the size of the internal array) separately from its size (the number of elements added), and the 'set' method depends on the index already having been assigned to an element. There isn't a way to set the size. If you need this, you can add dummy elements with a loop:

```
for (int i = 200; --i >= 0;) a.add(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once again JavaDoc to clarify the situation:

```
Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException 
    - if index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size()).
```

Note that `size()` returns the number of elements currently held by the List.

Answer (score 0):

`ensureCapacity` just makes sure that the underlying array's capacity is greater than or equal  to the argument. It doesn't change the size of the `ArrayList`. It does't make any changes visible through the API, so you won't notice a difference except that it will probably be longer before the `ArrayList` resizes it's internal array.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 190 null entries to an ArrayList reeks of a misuse of the data structure.

1. Think about using a standard primitive array.
2. If you require a generics or want more efficient use of space then consider `SparseArray` or even a `Map` like a `HashMap` may be appropriate for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void fillArrayList(ArrayList<String> arrayList, long size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
      arrayList.add(i,"-1");
    }
  }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(10);
  fillArrayList(a, 190);
  a.add(190,"test");
  System.out.println(a.get(190).toString());
}
```