# Java: Best way to store to an arbitrary index of an ArrayList

Tags: java, data-structures

I know that I cannot store a value at an index of an ArrayList that hasn't been used yet, i.e. is less than the size. In other words, if myArrayList.size() is 5, then if I try to do

```
myArrayList.set(10, "Hello World")
```

I will get an out of bounds error. But my app needs this. Other than a loop of storing null in each of the intermediate slots, is there a more elegant way?

It looks to me like:

- This behavior is the same in Vector
- If I need to be able to randomly access (i.e. element at pos X) then my choices are Vector and ArrayList.
- I could use a HashMap and use the index as a key but that's really inefficient.

So what is the elegant solution to what looks like a common case. I must be missing something...

Comment: Why do you say that the Map solution would be really inefficient? How strict are your space requirements?

Comment: Why is using a HashMap less efficient than the way you're proposing with an ArrayList?

Comment: Also, do you know beforehand what the highest index will be?

Comment: Why does your app need to do it? Maybe rather than trying to think of methods to use data structures in unintended ways you think about a different way to solve the problem?

Comment: Check out "Sparse Array", and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java

Comment: WOW! That was fast. I can't thank each person, but you've answered my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I could use a HashMap and use the index as a key but that's really inefficient.

Depends. If the indices you use are very sparse, it might be a lot better to use a Map. If the indices tend to be closely together, I think there is no better way than to fill it with nulls. Just write a utility function for it that you can use over and over instead of repeating the loop everywhere you need it, something like this:

```
private void padTo(List<?> list, int size) {
    for (int i=list.size(); i<size; i++)
        list.add(null);
}
```

Comment: Consider to call `list.ensureCapacity(size)` before loop to avoid unnecessary memory reallocations.

Comment: Note that ensureCapacity(size) doesn't actually pad the array - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688151/java-arraylist-ensurecapacity-not-working

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Map<Integer, MyClass>` instead. Specifically, if you use [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), it will also be `O(1)` - though it will be slower than `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TreeMap<key, value>`, which is sorted in natural order by the `value`.

Here you can keep value as the index. You can insert any value, it need not be in order. This seems the simplest solution.

Comment: More info about this: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained#specific-cases

Comment: TreeMap is sorted by its keys, not values

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a regular array:

- You want random access
- You want to specify some large size

Comment: You can specify the size of an ArrayList

Comment: Don't think so. It's the initial allocated capacity but the size is zero at the start.

Comment: Regular array is not an option if the items stored in the list are generic.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus it is an option, if you are ok with disregarding the unchecked assignment warning, and fully control what goes into that array and how it's read (i.e. you have to cast it)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus huh? java arrays have a type, although not implemented via generics, still typed. eg a `String[]` is different from a `Integer[]` and you'll get a compile error if you try the assign an object of the wrong type to an array element. There's no casting needed or desired, unless you use a `Object[]`, but that is obvious.

Comment: You can do it if you specify an array directly, but not when you have a generic container class and need the items in the array to be generic (i.e. of the generic parameter). You can do `new Arraylist<T>` but not `new T[]`. Note that the way `ArrayList` is implemented is by storing `Object[]` and lots of ugly casting. They can get away with unchecked casts because the array shouldn't leak to the outside. (however you can hack ArrayList and cause ClassCastExceptions using reflection)

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely have to use the list and not a map, then it's best you override the arraylist's add and set methods to first put a null in indexes before. No other better way IMO

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is probably much less inefficient than you think, try it. Otherwise, I can think of no way of doing it more elegantly than looping and filling with null. If you want elegance of exposition at least, then you could always subclass ArrayList and add an expandingSet(position, value) method to hide all the looping and such, or something. Perhaps this isn't an option though? If not just have a utility method somewhere else for it, but this is not as nice imho, though it will work also with other types of list too I guess...

Perhaps a wrapper class would be the best of both worlds, or perhaps it would just incur unnecessary overhead...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a sparse array (where most of the indices will be empty), a Map of some sort (probably a HashMap) will be your best bet.  Any array-esque solution will be forced to reserve space for all the empty indices, which is not very space-efficient, and a HashMap is fast enough for most normal purposes.

If you will eventually fill up the array up to some n, you will need to add nulls in a loop to get to the index you want.  You can make this somewhat more efficient by giving it an initial capacity of the number of elements you will eventually want to store (this prevents the ArrayList from needing to resize itself).  `new ArrayList(n)` will work fine.  Unfortunately, there is no simple way of making it a certain size to begin with except adding things in a loop when you make it.

Comment: I believe that sets up the 'capacity' not the 'size'

Comment: @pitosalas Good catch. Fixing it now.