# Gson: indexed object to list

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a json object from an external API that has a "list" of objects in the form of:

```
{
  "width": 10,
  "height": 20
  "pointData": {
    "0": {
      "x": 7,
      "y": 5,
      ...
    },
    "1": {
      "x": 4,
      "y": 20,
      ...
    },
    "2": {
      "x": 1,
      "y": 3,
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

My Deserializer and POJOs looks something like this:

```java
class KeyedListDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<List<T>> {

  @Override
  public List<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    List<T> things = new ArrayList<>();
    int key = 0;
    while (jsonObject.has(String.valueOf(key))) {
      JsonElement element = jsonObject.get(String.valueOf(key));
      T value = context.deserialize(element, new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType());
      things.add(value);
      key += 1;
    }
    return things;
  }
}

class PointDataKeyedList extends KeyedListDeserializer<PointData> {}

class Canvas {
  int width;
  int height;
  @JsonAdapter(PointDataKeyedList.class)
  List<PointData> pointData;
  ...
}

class PointData {
  int x;
  int y;
  ...
}
```

Since all the keys of the `pointData` object are just indices I thought I could just deserialize this as a list rather than a map. When running this, Gson successfully gets through deserialization, but when I try to access the point data, I get a:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class PointData (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap and PointData are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. I've read a bit about type erasure, which is something I've heard come up a lot when searching this problem, but I don't really understand it very well.

Comment: `"pointData": {}` is an invalid representation for an array; just replace to `[]` and parse it.

Comment: where do you declare the relationship between `KeyedList` and `KeyedListDeserializer`? (and what is a `KeyedList`?)

Comment: @njzk2 woops, I typoed when trying to transform my actual code into a question. The `KeyedList` was supposed to be `KeyedListDeserializer`. I called it `KeyedList` because it's technically a map, but the keys are just indices, so it's basically a list. I edited the code in the questions

Comment: @MartinZeitler the json is from an external API. I can't modify that

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to modify a string? You've probably missed the chapter about "input sanitizing"... and this would make parsing / mapping it a whole lot easier, eg. directly to `ArrayList<PointData>`, without having to mess around any further.

Comment: what happens when you run that in a debugger with a breakpoint inside `deserialize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy in Gson.

```java
public final class MapToListTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private MapToListTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( !List.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            return null;
        }
        final Type elementType = typeToken.getType() instanceof ParameterizedType
                ? ((ParameterizedType) typeToken.getType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]
                : Object.class;
        final TypeAdapter<?> elementTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(elementType));
        final TypeAdapter<List<Object>> listTypeAdapter = new TypeAdapter<List<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final List<Object> value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public List<Object> read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                in.beginObject();
                final ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
                while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                    final int index = Integer.parseInt(in.nextName());
                    final Object element = elementTypeAdapter.read(in);
                    ensureSize(list, index + 1);
                    list.set(index, element);
                }
                in.endObject();
                return list;
            }
        };
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) listTypeAdapter
                .nullSafe();
        return typeAdapter;
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688151/java-arraylist-ensurecapacity-not-working/7688171#7688171
    private static void ensureSize(final ArrayList<?> list, final int size) {
        list.ensureCapacity(size);
        while ( list.size() < size ) {
            list.add(null);
        }
    }

}
```

The type adapter factory above does the following things:

- checks if the target type is `List` (it does not really work with linked lists but it's fine for simplification);
- extracts the type parameter of the target list, hence its elements type and resolves a corresponding type adapter;
- substitutes the original type adapter with a map-reading one that reads map keys assuming them as the new list indices (and enlarges the result list if necessary) and reads every map value using the original element type adapter. Note that the assumption that the list may have sparse indices is vulnerable and I only put it for demo purposes (say, the input JSON declares a single-element map with the only index "999999" that enlarges the list dramatically), so you can ignore the `index` value using the `add(element)` method only.

Simply annotate the `pointData` field in the `Canvas` class with `@JsonAdapter(MapToListTypeAdapterFactory.class)` and it will work.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Looks like I was kinda close when I experimented with using a TypeAdapterFactory, but I never would have figured out all the type stuff. I've tried this out, and it works great. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @natebot13 You're welcome. I've just also checked your `KeyedListDeserializer` implementation and can tell why it does not work. The main and the only reason of the class cast exception is that `new TypeToken<T>()` does not work as you might think it could. Basically, the type it's resolved to becomes simply `java.lang.Object` so Gson does not have enough information to get the _real_ type of the object. This is why it picks the "unknown" target object deserializer and makes linked tree map objects out of it causing the runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid your POJO classes needs to be like

```
class Canvas {
  int width;
  int height;
  Map<String, PointData> pointData;
  ...
}

class PointData {
  int x;
  int y;
  ...
}
```

and you can get rid of PointDataKeyedList and KeyedListDeserializer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"width\": 10,\n" +
                "  \"height\": 20,\n" +
                "  \"pointData\": {\n" +
                "    \"0\": {\n" +
                "      \"x\": 7,\n" +
                "      \"y\": 5\n" +

                "    },\n" +
                "    \"1\": {\n" +
                "      \"x\": 4,\n" +
                "      \"y\": 20\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"2\": {\n" +
                "      \"x\": 1,\n" +
                "      \"y\": 3\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        System.out.println(json);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Canvas canvas = gson.fromJson(json, Canvas.class);
        System.out.println(canvas);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know I could do this, but since the data is just a map with indices as keys, I thought I might be able to transform it into an actual list upon deserialization.